# Inner Div not getting parent div height

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an outer div with a few inner divs like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix bigBox">
   <div class="bigBoxBody">
      <div class="containerWithHeaderContent">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content .bigBox {
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    width: 100%;
}
#content .containerWithHeader, .containerWithHeaderContent {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

My problem is that the inner div (`bigBoxBody`) does not seem to be getting the height in line with the height of the outer div (`bigBox`).

Screen shot:

(The outer div is red, and the inner div is green.)
[image]

I am not sure what is wrong with this, or if there are any other things that need to be taken care of using CSS.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UFFx3/2/

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking?. Can you please explain it.

Comment: @bharathi: i was afraid that my question is not making sense.my issue is the inner div seems to be gettind placed outside parent div.will try to add a screen shot.

Comment: @Brian:`display:block` to which div?

Comment: the inner div should have it

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net/hCtfa/1/

Comment: @Brian: i m doing that, will update my question with this info soon

Comment: @Brian: i have created a jsfiddle example to explian my issue http://jsfiddle.net/UFFx3/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divs won't naturally occupy the full vertical space available to them. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCNDq/4/) for an example. The outer div is given an explicit height of 100 pixels, and the inner div has no height specified at all. The inner div thus only take up the space needed to display its contents.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <p>Content here!</p>       
   </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
.inner {
    background: green;
}
```

​
If you want the inner div to take up all the vertical space available, set `height:100%` in the CSS. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCNDq/5/) for an example.

**New CSS:**

```
.outer {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
.inner {
    background: green;
    height: 100%; /* new line */
}
```

I'm not sure if there are any more specifics to your problem as you are using a `clearfix` CSS class that isn't shown in your example. Please let me know if there's something else missing for you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thats one thing I am not a fan of in css, is the way the heights function, especially when it come to percentage. In theory, you should be able to have 1 div on a page, give it a height of 100% and have it fill the page, and not have to wrap another div around it with a set height...

Comment: Have you tried setting `height:100%` to the inner div? It looks like the green div is auto-sizing to fit the book titles, but it gets messed up due to floating in some way. I need to see the actual code content for the entire page to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @AndersHolmström: yes i tried with height 100%, here is a sample exmaple http://jsfiddle.net/UFFx3/2/

Comment: Remove `padding-bottom: 9px;` from `#content .bigBox` and it covers the entire parent. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/UFFx3/5/

Comment: @AndersHolmström: that's strange in my webpage its still same even after removing that `padding-bottom`

Comment: @AndersHolmström:i have updated the example see http://jsfiddle.net/UFFx3/11/. Please do not pay much attention to my messed up CSS

Comment: Well - now you have two inner divs that both need to expand to 100% height for this to work. I have added `height:100%` to `#content .coverBigBox .bigBoxContent` as well as `#content .coverBigBox .coverRow`. See http://jsfiddle.net/UFFx3/13/

Comment: @AndersHolmström:Thanks it helped me to slove my issues and confusion except one, when i was using height `#content .bigBox` as 100% is was not diaplying correclty while on setting heigh say `200px;` , it worked can you help me to understand this?

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you! That's because `.bigBox` is nested inside of #content. When you tell `.bigBox` to have a height of 100%, it basically means "have the same height as your parent"... however in this case, `#content` doesn't have a height set explicitly, and so it will shrink to a minimum size.

Answer (score 0):

In your case (from the screen shot) it seems that the inner div is not expanding to the content inside it. Therefore its not a case of having the inner div expand to the height of the outer div but rather have the inner div accept to expand to the content inside it.

therefore I advice you try setting the inner div to contain `overflow:auto` and remove the height constraint on the outer div to allow infinite growth in height as follows

```
.outer {
    background: red;
}
.inner {
    background: green;
    overflow : auto;
}
```